# Hibernate can't delete object

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities Company and Menu
Company has many menus.

Company Entity:

```
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "company")
    private Set<Menu> menus;

    //other fields getters and setters
```

Menu Entity:

```
public class Menu {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
    private Company company;

//other fields getters and setters
```

When I delete company it works properly, removes company with its menus, but I cant delete  directly menu: Api returns no error but doesn`t delete record from database.

Service:

```
    public boolean deleteMenu(long id) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        try{
            menuRepository.deleteMenuById(id);
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

MenuRepository:

```
public interface MenuRepository extends CrudRepository<Menu, Long> {
    public Menu findMenuById(Long id);
    public void deleteMenuById(long id);
}
```

**EDIT**

As I guess the problem is that transaction rolls back changes in this case, I cought this error: 
Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

Comment: How does `menuRepository` look like?

Comment: I added menuRepository in my question, can it be a problem of relation with company? because for other entities delete works properly, I have problem just for this case

Comment: You already inherit `findById()` and `deleteById()` methods from CrudRepository so why are you defining similar methods?

Comment: findbyId is optional type method and i needed Menu type for my service, and i tried 
deleteMenuById because inherited method was not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the throws statement on your delete method is stopping you from catching the actual exception being thrown.`throws ResourceNotFoundException` will not help you.

Secondly, change your cascade to cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE

Comment: No its not a problem, problem is that delete method returns true, without any error. But it doesnt delete record from database.